# extract data from array that begins with "http" only

Tags: php

I have an array `$all_urls`. If I do `print_r($all_urls);`, it will return the following data:

```
Array (
[0] => http://www.domain.com
[1] => https://www.domain.com
[2] => http://www.domain.com/my-account/
[3] => https://www.facebook.com/
[4] => /test
[5] => http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/logos-5.jpg 
[6] => 'http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/'
[7] => '//mattressandmore.com/wp-content/plugins'
)
```

I would like to extract and list the items that contain "http://" only.

Comment: try to code something first, a foreach is a start

Comment: that begins with 'http://' or has 'http://' in it? ie, should element 6 in your array match?

Comment: @pala_ correct, it should be a match

Comment: Then are you sure the answer you commented on after changing the regexp actually works? it is looking for http only at the _start_ of a string

Comment: @pala_ hmm no it didnt.. i didnt realise until you mentioned it but it isnt including the 6th element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function like this:

```
array_walk($all_urls, function(function(&$value, $index){
    if (preg_match('/^http/', $value)) {
        echo $index . " " . $value . "\n";
    }
});
```

Also you can just iterate on array with foreach:

```
foreach($all_urls as $index => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/^http/', $value)) {
        echo $index . " " . $value . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. The second solution works well but it did return some https:// whereas i only want http://.. i just updated the preg_match to `'/^http:/'` and it works pefectly

Comment: and finally, if no matches found, how to echo "now matches found" ?

Comment: @user3436467 remove the `^` from `^http` to change it to match anywhere in the string

Comment: also just noticed the 6th element didnt appear, the one that contains a apostrophe at the begining and end `'http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/'`

Comment: okay great. removing the `^` worked.. just need to include if no matches found echo "no matches found"

Comment: Yes, but... it will stop loop at second item (when match not found). If that's your intention - great. :)

Comment: @nevermind, after some testing i don't think `else` does the job. I need it to check `$value` and if no urls contain "http://" then it should echo "no matches found" else if it does then run the foreach statement to return the output..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to filter only the values that begin with `http` and return a new array:

```
array_filter($arr, function ($var) {
    return stripos($var, 'http', -strlen($var)) !== FALSE;
});
```